# Why is window autoreleased in appliciation:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and released in dealloc?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2, autorelease

I have created an iphone application using the empty template without ARC in xcode 4.2. I'm not currently using ARC because I want to learn the basics of reference counting. In the application delegate I have the following method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
 }
```

Why is `window` autoreleased? Is it because AppDelegate won't be using it in the future? But it is being assigned to a instance variable. There is also a dealloc method where `window` is released. Why is it released when it is already autoreleased?

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property of the `window` in `.h` file is declared as `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;`. The `window` has a `retain` property. So the `UIWindow` is retained by the setter method of the `window` variable. 
In the line `self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];` the new `window` `alloc`ed has `+1` in `retainCount` because of the `alloc` and another `+1` because of the `window` setter method resulting in a `+2` `retainCount`. The `autorelease` is to decrease the `retainCount` back to `+1`. In the `dealloc` the `retainCount` goes to `0` and the `window` is deallocated.

Comment: Thanks! That explains everything.

Comment: If it was directly assigned (window = .... instead of self.window = ...) it wouldn't be necessary right?

Comment: Right, the retainCount would be +1 because of the alloc. In the dealloc would go back to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Every `retain`, `alloc`, `copy` and `new`, must be balanced by `release` or `autorelease`.

---

So in you're code:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
```

The `alloc` is balanced by the `autorelease`.

---

Now for the `release` in dealloc, if you look at the definition of the `window` property, you will see it is a retained proerty: (in your AppDelegate header)

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

or the more modern equivalent: (where the strong means retain in this case)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

This means you know have one outstanding `retain`, as the @property and @synthesize is there to stop you have to write boilerplate code over and over again.

So this must be balanced by the `release` in the `dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`window` is retained by the property, so when creating it you shouldn't leave t retained (which is what alloc/init does). It is autoreleased because it is easier than just releasing (releasing would work as well). It has to be release in dealloc to counter the retain nature of the property.